# hyperlink in a package

Tags: hyperlink

I want to give a map that contains hyperlinks as a package of Adobe or
an exe file to someone who does not have access to ArcMap. This
package should have just some points and polygons that when he click
on each of them, a file which is linked to that point or polygon
opens.

How can I do that?

Comment: are you trying to give hyperlink to PDF files... or exe files when clicked runs programs in the background..can you be more specific.